# Create form with has_many relationship ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

I am trying to create a form that will allow a group to select multiple modules that they can use in the system. unfortunately every time I try this I keep getting some crazy association error and I have no clue why.

Here is the code for my form

```
<%= form_for @group, :url => admin_groups_path, :html => { :class => 'entry' } do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/error_messages', :locals => { :object => @group } %>

  <div class="g12">
    <fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Group</legend>
        <div class="simple_format">
          <section class="g3">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <div><%= f.text_field :name, :size => 15 %></div>
          </section>
          <section class="g3">
            <%= f.label :is_facility, 'Facility?' %>
            <div style="display:block;margin: 0 auto;width:25px;"><%= f.check_box :is_facility %></div>
          </section>
          <section class="g3">
            <%= f.label :parent_id %>
            <div style="display:block;margin: 0 auto;width:25px;"><%= f.collection_select :parent_id, current_group.self_and_descendants.reject(&:is_facility), :id, :name %></div>
          </section>
          <section class="g3">
            <%= f.label :time_zone, 'Time Zone' %>
            <div><%= f.select :time_zone,  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name).select {|x| x=~ /US/} %></div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="simple_format">
          <section class="g3">
            <%= f.label :federal_tax_number, 'Federal Tax ID' %>
            <div><%= f.text_field :federal_tax_number, :size => 15 %></div>
          </section>
          <section class="g3">
            <%= f.label :national_provider_identifier, 'National Provider ID' %>
            <div><%= f.text_field :national_provider_identifier, :size => 15 %></div>
          </section>
          <section class="g3">
            <%= f.label :modules, 'Allowed Modules' %>
            <div><%= f.collection_select :group_access_modules, AccessModule.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true} %></div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <section class="g12">
          <div><%= f.submit "Add Group", { :class => 'form-submit' } %></div>
        </section>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_access_modules
end
```

Here is the error I get on save

```
<h1>
  ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch
    in Admin::GroupsController#create
</h1>
<pre>GroupAccessModule(#70245162706560) expected, got String(#70245155065480)</pre>
```

I am completely lost right now.

Comment: Please post your GroupsController code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fields_for` for your association in your form. It should look something like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :group_access_modules do |g| %>
  <%= g.collection_select(:group_id, AccessModule.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true} %>
<% end %>
```

Note: it may be necessary to change the method (`:group_id`) if you are using an unconventional foreign key name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)? it makes associations for has many relationships quite easy, for example:

```
 <%= f.association :company %>
```

obviously, this makes your code easier to read and it's pretty configurable.

There is also the [railscast on habtm checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised) but this is a revised episode which I think you need a subscription for.

let me know what you think of the simple_form gem